# Converting from Java 7 to 6, Matcher.group

Tags: java, java-7, java-6, matcher

I'm converting a Java 7 application to a Java 6 application. I'm stuck on the `matcher.group` property, since I don't really understand what it does.

I have the following code:

```
public static final String PropertyRegexPrefixGroup = "prefix";
public static final String PropertyRegexPostfixGroup = "postFix";

public static ParsedProperty parse(String property) {
    Matcher matcher = PropertyRegex.matcher(property);
    boolean isMatch = matcher.matches();
    if (!isMatch)
        return new ParsedProperty(null, property, false);

    String prefix = matcher.group(PropertyParser.PropertyRegexPrefixGroup);
    String postfix = matcher.group(PropertyParser.PropertyRegexPostfixGroup);
    return new ParsedProperty(prefix, postfix, true);
}
```

I have to rewrite the `String prefix` and `String postfix` property declarations. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java 6, you can't have named groups, so you need to reference the groups by index.

Given this pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(foo).*(bar)")
```

and this code:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("foo....something...else...bar");
matcher.find();
```

`matcher.group(0)` matches the entire String, `matcher.group(1)` returns "foo" and `matcher.group(2)` returns "bar"